# Can the proof of fixed point theorems ever be constructive?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, fixed-point-theorems, constructive-mathematics

Overall, Brouwer fixed point theorem and Kakutani fixed theorem are non-constructive. Is there any established paper that demonstrates that there exists constructive proofs that do exactly what these theorems do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are constructive proofs for fixed point theorems including [Brouwer](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2156239?uid=3739808&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104002276711). Also, the [proof of the Banach fixed point theorem with which I am most familiar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) is constructive. In fact, here is a paper all about constructive methods for fixed point theorems:

- Hendtlass, Matthew. [*Fixed point theorems in constructive mathematics*](http://logicandanalysis.org/index.php/jla/article/view/157/58). Journal of Logic and Analysis 4:10 (2012) 1–20. ISSN 1759-9008.

Comment: So that means we can find an algorithm for computing a fixed point? (for irrational numbers, standard interpretation of computing "reals" apply)

Comment: This is not really a constructive proof of Brouwer's FPT. At least in the sense in which constructive mathematics is understood.